# Why was this encryption question closed as off-topic as a bug even though it isn't a bug?

Tags: discussion

I hit a problem about encryption on 18.04, and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1024889/2088) was perfect. However, it was closed as off-topic saying that it should be reported as a bug.

However, this isn't a bug — it's a [deliberate decision](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1756840) by Canonical. The poster is asking how to apply the alternative route that Canonical itself recommends, which I think is a valid question.

So, should this question really have been closed as off-topic? Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it was off topic when it was written, no it is not a bug but the other reason given is "problems specific to development version of Ubuntu" and, when it was posted, Apr 14th, 18.04 was not released, April 26th , so the close was correct.

Some choices you have here are: Ask a new question now it is on topic or vote to reopen the question now 18.04 is out.

Comment: Thank you, that helps.